# MapView extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity

Tags: android, api, dictionary, android-mapview

I have a question . I'm trying to use MapView in Google Maps Android API v2 . I'm read in document . They said that

MapView, a subclass of the Android View class, allows you to place a map in an Android View. A View represents a rectangular region of the screen, and is a fundamental building block for Android applications and widgets. Much like a MapFragment, the MapView acts as a container for the Map, exposing core map functionality through the GoogleMap object.

It may be MapView and MapFragment are the same thing . In Google Maps Android API v1 , MapView extend MapActivity . But in Google Maps Android API v2 , I can use it any more . I see the tutorial

[How do you display Google Maps via new Google Maps API v2 on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037779/how-to-display-google-map-via-new-google-maps-api-v2-on-android)

They advice to extend FragmentActivity . But in my layout xml , I just use

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

It doesn't have prefix fragment like MapFragment . And when it displays , It looks like when I use MapFragment . May be both of them is the same thing ???? I'm not clear about that . Anyone can explain for me . Sorry my English is not good !!!

Comment: *It may be MapView and MapFragment are the same thing*. A `MapFragment` will certainly contain a `MapView`, but not the other way around. One's a `Fragment`, One's a `View`, they're most certainly not the same.

Comment: Can you add more details ????